# JS: writing JSON file's content to a textarea and input field fails without error

Tags: javascript, filereader

I'm trying to read the content of the JSON file defined by the user. The JSON object ideally contains an `id` and a `request`. If this is the case, these parameters should be printed respectively into an input field and a textarea.

I managed to print them on the console; however, the content of the HTML fields does not change. Besides, I don't see any error messages on the console. [image: console_output]

Here is my code:

```
readJSONAfterRendering: function() {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function() {
      var data = JSON.parse(reader.result);

      if (typeof data.id != 'undefined') {
        console.log(data.id);
        $('#queryIdInput').attr('value', data.id);
      } else {
        alert("Input does not contain ID!");
      }

      if (typeof data.request != 'undefined') {
        console.log(data.request);
        App.queryString = JSON.stringify(data.request);
        $('#queryStringInput').html(JSON.stringify(data.request));
      } else {
        alert("Input does not contain request!");
      }
    }

    var fileInput = document.getElementById("queryFile");
    reader.readAsText(fileInput.files[0]);
  }
```

The relevant HTML:

```
    <div id="content">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <label for="queryIdInput">Query ID</label>
          <input class="form-control" id="queryIdInput">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <label for="queryStringInput">Query string</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="queryStringInput"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
          <label for="queryFile">Query input</label>
          <input type="file" id="queryFile">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

And the function mentioned above is bound to the change event of the input field with the `queryFile` ID:

```
$('#queryFile').bind('change', function() {
    App.readJSONAfterRendering();
});
```

Comment: Please post some html-code to help clear things up...

Comment: Sure, I have added some html to the answer

Comment: There must be something else affecting your script, cause it should work. That is: unless you have errors of some sort. Another thing though: I dont see why you are using JSON.stringify on the request-data, seems strange.